# suffix of the generated tar.gz in maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

Maven assembly plugin adds a suffix to the generated tar.gz which value is value of the **<id>** when there are more than one descriptor files, like here:

```
<descriptors>
    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/bin-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/test-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
</descriptor>
```

generated files are: project-1.0.0-bin.tar.gz and project-1.0.0-test.tar.gz. When there is only one file in the descriptors, like here:

```
<descriptors>
    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/bin-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
</descriptor>
```

the output is: project-1.0.0.tar.gz. How to force maven assembly to add a suffix to the name when there is only one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange, I'm using Maven 3.0.1 and it also adds the assembly `id` as a prefix when I use only one descriptor. It's the default behaviour I think.

Try to force it configuring the [`appendAssemblyId`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html#appendAssemblyId) to `true`.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason, just noticed that appendAssemblyId is set to false for the single descriptor file.